# ESS major modes keybindings do not work

Tags: key-bindings, linux, ess

I am connecting from a Windows machine to a Linux server via Putty (http://blog.harang.org/?tag=putty). There I start Emacs and open a script written in the statistical language R. When I open the file, the appropriate major mode ESS is loaded and shown to be active in the tool bar. Also when I type `C-h m` I get the information of the major mode and also all its keybinding. The variable `major-mode` has the value `ess-mode`.

So far, so good. The problem is: None of the keybindings associated with this major mode do work. I type one of them, nothing happens except that I get the message that this keybinding is undefined. In `describe-bindings`, the keybindings of the major mode are not shown. (This is also the information I get when I type `C-h k` with the key sequence.)

What can I do? What is going on? Is it because of the putty emulation I am using?

Comment: What is the value of `major-mode`? What does `M-x` `describe-bindings` say?

Comment: I am the question asker. As I cannot respond to the comments of the questions I do it here: 1. The variable major mode has value "ess-mode". 2. In `describe-bindings`, the keybindings of the major mode are not shown.

Comment: I'm having trouble following what's happening. Does `C-h k` report the key that you thought you had pressed? Could you post a screenshot after pressing `C-h k` and one of the major mode key bindings? Are you sure that the right window is focused?

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`.